# Como funcionam os tipos valor e tipos referência em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, memória, tipagem

Eu sei que em C# existem tipos valor e tipos referência e uma das diferenças entre eles é no gerenciamento da memória. O que decide como as variáveis vão se comportar é o tipo delas, então se for um `int` vai ser tipo valor, se for instância de uma classe `Cliente`, por exemplo, vai ser um tipo referência.

No Javascript não tem diferença de tipos. Todas as variáveis são instanciadas com a palavra-chave `var`. Então como funciona o gerenciamento de memória no Javascript? Existe essa diferença, de algumas variáveis serem armazenadas diretamente na pilha e outras serem armazenadas no *heap* somente tendo uma referência na pilha?

Comment: Sua definição do C# ficou meio vaga. A diferença entre tipos de referência e de valor é basicamente a declaração. `struct`s são valor, `class`es são referência.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse material. Possui informações a respeito da linguagem com relação a gerencia de memória. Creio que é isso que desejas saber.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FMemory_Management

Comment: Sim, eu sei @AndréLeria, eu só citei um exemplo. Obrigado por completar.

Comment: Não quis ser rude, só esclarecer mesmo. Seu exemplo foi bom de qualquer maneira.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> No Javascript não tem diferença de tipos. Todas as variáveis são instanciadas com a palavra-chave `var`.

#### JavaScript tem sim um sistema de tipos

Quando você armazena um valor em uma variável, esse valor tem um tipo. O tipo de um dado valor nunca muda, mas o valor guardado numa variável pode ser trocado. Qualquer variável pode conter um valor de qualquer tipo, a qualquer momento, e por isso não faz sentido declarar o tipo da variável. O tipo é uma característica dos valores, e as variáveis (pense nelas como lugares onde se guardam valores) são agnósticas quanto a eles. Em outras palavras, as variáveis não são amarradas a nenhum tipo, mas sempre contêm valores que pertencem a algum dos tipos disponíveis.

#### Os tipos

Cinco dos seis tipos em JavaScript têm valores *primitivos*: Undefined, Null, Boolean, String e Number. Valores primitivos como `undefined`, `null`, `true`, `"texto"` e `10` são imutáveis. Undefined e Null são tipos especiais que possuem um só valor cada, respectivamente `undefined` e `null`.

O sexto tipo é Object, que inclui arrays, funções e outros. Objetos são conjuntos de propriedades, que podem guardar valores de qualquer um dos tipos já citados. Propriedades podem ser acrescentadas a um objeto ou removidas dele a qualquer momento, e valores de propriedades também podem ser alterados. Portanto, objetos são mutáveis.

Existem ainda outros tipos que a especificação define para uso próprio, para descrever como a linguagem deve funcionar. Eles não estão disponíveis para os usuários da linguagem (nós), nem precisam ter correspondentes diretos na implementação.

#### Valor *versus* referência

Eu não conheço bem o C#, mas pelo que entendi sobre *value types* e *reference types*, é possível traçar um paralelo com o JavaScript. Deixe de lado a questão do local de alocação, que discutirei mais adiante, e foque no comportamento dos tipos quando um valor é atribuído a uma variável ou passado para uma função ou método.

Pode-se considerar que os tipos primitivos do JavaScript funcionam como os *value types*, enquanto que os objetos funcionam como os *reference types*. Vou explicar com um exemplo:

```
var meuObjeto = {};
```

Aqui cria-se um objeto, que fica guardado na variável `meuObjeto`. Mas será mesmo? O que é guardado nessa variável é um valor do tipo Object. O objeto em si (com suas propriedades, métodos, etc.) fica guardado em algum lugar da memória, gerenciado pelo interpretador da linguagem. E o valor do tipo Object é uma *referência* a esse objeto.

Dizer que objetos são referências quer dizer apenas que com a referência em mãos você pode acessar o objeto, e **não** que a referência seja um ponteiro para o local onde o objeto está armazenado na memória. Essa distinção é muito importante. Pense na referência como um valor como qualquer outro. Agora considere o seguinte exemplo:

```
var a, b;
a = {};
b = a;
b.umaPropriedade = "um valor";
b == a; // true
a.umaPropriedade; // "um valor"
b = { outroObjeto: true };
b == a; // false
```

Aqui, `b` não é "uma referência a `a`"; `b` contém uma referência a um determinado objeto, e `a` contém **outra** referência **ao mesmo objeto**. Assim, pode-se alterar uma propriedade desse mesmo objeto por meio de `a` ou `b`. Mas não se pode sobrescrever o objeto que está em `a` por atribuição de um novo valor a `b`. O que `b = { outroObjeto: true }` faz é somente armazenar em `b` uma nova referência, a um outro objeto. O primeiro objeto continua existindo, e a referência contida em `a` ainda aponta para ele.

Esse mesmo conceito também serve para entender como os objetos são passados para funções:

```
function teste(obj) {
    obj.novaProp = "foo";        // o objeto fora da função é afetado
    obj = { outraProp: "bar" };  // o objeto fora da função NÃO é afetado
}
var o = {};
teste(o);
o.novaProp;  // "foo"
o.outraProp; // undefined
```

Isso quer dizer que em JavaScript não existe passagem "por referência". O objeto é passado por valor, só que o valor passado em `teste(o)` é uma referência.

> Então como funciona o gerenciamento de memória no Javascript? Existe essa diferença, de algumas variáveis serem armazenadas diretamente na pilha e outras serem armazenadas no heap somente tendo uma referência na pilha?

Ao programar em JavaScript, tenha em mente que o acesso à memória fica a cargo do interpretador da linguagem. Não se manipula a memória diretamente em JavaScript. A especificação da linguagem sequer menciona como a memória deve ser tratada, isso fica integralmente a cargo da implementação. Por isso não é possível dizer onde cada dado fica armazenado sem conhecer bem como cada interpretador funciona. Eu não conheço isso, então não posso afirmar nada a respeito.

Mas se você está preocupado com o uso de memória pelo seu JavaScript, lembre-se do seguinte:

- Existe um *garbage collector* nos *engines* de JavaScript
- Esse *garbage collector* é executado em momentos arbitrários (geralmente quando o interpretador não está ocupado com o seu código)
- O *garbage collector* só liberar a memória ocupada por um objeto se não houver nenhuma referência "viva" a esse objeto.
- Ou seja: cuidado com objetos capturados em *closures*, eles podem acabar ocupando memória eternamente!

---

<sub>As dúvidas que me surgiram ao preparar e finalizar esta resposta geraram uma [pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554770/how-to-explain-object-references-in-ecmascript-terms), com uma resposta bem interessante.</sub>

Comment: Quando diz arbitrário é arbitrário mesmo (já vi casos) ou não é determinístico? Só sendo chato, isso pode variar de acordo com implementação. Acho que essa parte da *closure* manter o objeto eternamente é verdade, mas não é culpa da *closure* e sim onde ela foi usada.

Comment: Eu quis dizer que do ponto de vista do programador parece arbitrário/aleatório, está fora do controle dele. Mas na prática acredito que seja determinístico na maioria dos casos, né? Sobre closures, está meio solto mesmo o que eu falei, foi mais uma dica porque o uso descuidado de closures é uma das principais causas de memory leaks em js.

Comment: Em JS eu não sei, e acho que deve depender da implementação. Em C# não é determinístico, mas não é arbitrário. Tem um jeito de não disparar uma coleta. Nunca faça uma alocação, porque é na alocação que pode disparar a coleta, e só se atingir um certo critério. Já vi GC que é arbitrário, ele dispara em "qualquer" momento. No C# não importante se está fazendo algo importante ou não, ele dispara quando precisa liberar memória no critério estabelecido, nada mais é olhado. Não sei se em JS tem áreas protegidas.

Answer (score 9):

Javascript tem uma diferença entre os tipos de dados sim, apesar de ser uma linguagem de [tipagem fraca](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipo_de_dado#Tipo_forte_e_fraco). Você pode encontrar os tipos de dados que o javascript oferece suporte [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/JavaScript/Guia/Valores,_Vari%C3%A1veis_e_Literais).

Por isso, Javascript não permite a passagem de valores por referência, mas é possível contornar essa [limitação passando um objeto como parâmetro](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jspro/0Zqf7GTAEVM), como pode ser visto no exemplo a seguir:

```
var A = new Array();

function swap(A, a, b){
        var c = A[a];
        A[a] = A[b];
        A[b] = c;
}
```

E, além de ser fracamente tipada, como a maioria das linguagens de script, o Javascript tem [tipagem dinâmica](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_tipos), o que, junto ao fato de ser fracamente tipada, torna a linguagem mais dinâmica.

Comment: Então, números, booleans, strings, null e undefined são como os tipos valor do C#, armazenados diretamente na pilha enquanto que objetos são como os tipos referência, criados no heap contendo referências na pilha? Obrigado.

Comment: Basicamente, sim.

Answer (score 3):

Em Javascript existem tipos **Primitivos** e tipos **Complexos**.

Primitivos seriam string, number, boolean e undefined.
Tipos primitivos são copiados por valor.
Então:

```
var x = 1, y = x;
x = 2;
console.log(x);//vai mostrar 1
```

Complexos são objects, functions e arrays.
Tipos complexos são copiados por referência.
Então:

```
var x = [1,2], y = x;
y[0] = 3;
console.log(x);//vai mostrar [3,2]
```

Então acredito que seja parecido com C#.

Referência: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#types

Answer (score 1):

Javascript é uma linguagem "fracamente tipada".

O tipo da variável é determinado pelo interpretador em tempo de execução e pode ser alterado durante a execução do programa, conforme o conteúdo da variável é alterado.

Diversas linguagens que são definidas dessa forma, principalmente linguagens interpretadas como javascript.