# Por que apontar para o mesmo endereço de memória muda um objeto?

Tags: javascript, array, memória

Se eu executo o seguinte código:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = a
```

Neste caso, a variável 'a' e 'b' estão apontando para o mesmo endereço de memória, consequentemente, tudo o que eu mudar em 'a', teoricamente vai ser mudado em 'b'. Por exemplo:

```
a[0] = 4
console.log(b)
> [4, 2, 3]
```

Até então, tudo certo. Mas, se eu faço alguma dessas coisas que eu vou anexar abaixo, parece que automaticamente 'a' e 'b' deixam de apontar para o mesmo endereço. Por exemplo:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(b)
> [4, 2, 3]
```

ou

```
a = {nome: 'Gustavo', sobrenome: 'Paiva'}
console.log(b)
> [4, 2, 3]
```

ou

```
a = 23
console.log(b)
> [4, 2, 3]
```

Por que isso acontece?

Depois dessas coisas, sinto que não entendi muito bem o conceito de 'apontar para o mesmo endereço de memória'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade essa ideia de apontar está ligeiramente errada. Até existe isso sim, mas vamos começar pelo fim que você entende melhor.

Quando você atribui 23 para a variável `a` é bem fácil de entender. Está colocando um objeto numérico cujo valor é 23 no local de armazenamento com um nome chamado `a`.

Se não entende isso precisa ler [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

E se você colocar o número 12 em `a`?

Está colocando um **outro** objeto numérico cujo valor é 12. Notou o destaque?

Acho que deu para entender que o valor anterior é descartado.

Você pode fazer isso quanto quiser.

E em JavaScript pode colocar objetos de outros tipos porque é uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica, então só os objetos possuem tipos, a variável não.

O que acontece se você fizer como no começo e agora atribuir um *array* para `a`? O que será armazenado em `a`?

## Tipos por valor X tipo por referência

O que eu mostrei inicialmente é o tipo por valor que é mais fácil de entender. O objeto vai direto na variável.

Acontece que existem os tipos por referência. Eles são tipos que dependem de [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101). Então você tem uma referência que é um ponteiro para outro objeto e em outro lugar diferente tem o objeto de fato.

Isso é necessário porque esse objeto tem um tamanho a ser definido, não há como reservar memória previamente no local de armazenamento da variável. Mesmo que soubesse o tamanho ele poderia ser muito grande.

Qual é o valor que vai na variável? O valor do ponteiro, que é um endereço de memória para onde de fato está o objeto, aí entra o apontamento.

Quando `a` vale 23 e você fizer:

```
b = a
```

você está copiando o objeto numérico que tem o valor 23 que está em `a` para o local de `b`. Você terá duas variáveis como o mesmo valor, apesar de serem objetos diferentes, fisicamente existem dois. Simples.

Mas o que está copiando quando tem um objeto for por referência como o *array*?

Está copiando a referência, o ponteiro. Então você terá duas variáveis com o mesmo valor, um endereço de memória apontando para o mesmo objeto. Isso você pode observar. Quando você mudou a composição do objeto por uma variável o objeto mudou pela outra porque é o mesmo objeto. Dois ponteiros mas só um objeto.

Mas o que aconteceu quando fez isto?

```
a = [1, 2, 3] //isto é um literal de criação de array
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/ValueXReference.js).

Você acabou de criar um objeto **novo** e atribui para `a` o endereço à ela. E o que aconteceu com `b`? Continuou apontando para o objeto que ele estava apontando antes, ninguém mexeu em `b`.

Então agora você tem `a` apontando para um objeto que acabou de ser criado e `b` apontando para outro objeto que já existia antes. Não tem mais duas variáveis apontando para o mesmo objeto.

Notou que o valor que estava em `a` que era a referência para o primeiro objeto foi descartada? Aconteceu igual ao tipo por valor `23`, ele foi descartado. Não necessariamente o objeto apontado. De fato o objeto ainda existe porque `b` continua apontando para ele. Se ninguém apontasse para esse objeto mais ele seria descartado também. Esse é o mecanismo do tipo por referência.

Se o objetivo fosse entender o gerenciamento da memória de como isso acontece a pergunta seria outra.

## Conclusão

Então é isso, em tipos por valor você sempre cria novos objetos quando atribui algo à variável, em tipos por referência só em algumas situações é que isso acontece, só cria um novo objeto **se mandar** criar um novo objeto. Atribuir `b = a` em um tipo por referência não está criando um novo objeto, só quando você usa uma sintaxe que claramente é um literal de novo objeto é que está criando algo novo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, não teria como dar uma explicação melhor!

Comment: Relacionado/complementar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2695/como-funcionam-os-tipos-valor-e-tipos-referência-em-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Quando usas o `let` (ou `var`) dás um valor a essa variável. Quando atribuis um novo valor a essa variável ela perde a relação com os seus valores anteriores. Ou seja:

```
let a = 2;
a = 3; // dá 3
```

Da mesma maneira a variável perde a ligação a esse ponteiro, que no teu exemplo continua a existir em `b`.

Não é mais complicado que isso: atribuir um novo valor a uma variável "corta" a ligação ao seu valor anterior.